# Is there a way to get the parameters of a command?

Tags: discord.py

I was wondering if there is a way to get the parameters of a command to show how to use it. I have a custom help command, but I tried doing something that uses the same description thing that you put in the decorator. It doesn't work (doesn't give me any errors or anything) but I don't know why.

```
@commands.command()
    async def format(self, ctx, command):
        formatting = discord.Embed(title=f"Formatting for .{command}", description=command.description)
        formatting.set_thumbnail(url=self.bot.avatar_url)
        formatting.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.mention}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        ctx.send(embed=formatting)
```

Here's one of my commands that has the description thing:

```
"""Change Nickname command"""
    @commands.command(aliases=['chnick'], description="Usage: .nick [member mention] [nickname to change to]")
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def change_nick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
        """Changes a user's nickname\nAliases: chnick"""

        await member.edit(nick=nick)
        await ctx.send(f"Nickname was changed for {member.mention}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the command using `get_command()`

```py
@commands.command()
async def format(self, ctx, command):
    command = self.bot.get_command(command)
    formatting = discord.Embed(title=f"Formatting for .{command.name}", description=command.description)
    formatting.set_thumbnail(url=self.bot.avatar_url)
    formatting.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.mention}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=formatting)
```

Comment: I tried it out, but it still didn't work. Is it because description is something that's only used with the default help command?